# SQL Server Indexing and Composite Keys

Tags: sql-server-2016

Given the following:

```
-- This table will have roughly 14 million records
CREATE TABLE IdMappings 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    OldId int NOT NULL,
    NewId int NOT NULL,
    RecordType varchar(80) NOT NULL, -- 15 distinct values, will never increase
    Processed bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

    CONSTRAINT pk_IdMappings 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC)
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_IdMappings_OldId ON IdMappings (OldId);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_IdMappings_NewId ON IdMappings (NewId);
```

and this is the most common query run against the table:

```
WHILE @firstBatchId <= @maxBatchId
BEGIN
    -- the result of this is used to insert into another table:
    SELECT
        NewId, -- and lots of non-indexed columns from SOME_TABLE
    FROM
        IdMappings map
    INNER JOIN
        SOME_TABLE foo ON foo.Id = map.OldId
    WHERE
        map.Id BETWEEN @firstBatchId AND @lastBatchId
        AND map.RecordType = @someRecordType
        AND map.Processed = 0

    -- We only really need this in case the user kills the binary or SQL Server service:
    UPDATE IdMappings 
    SET Processed = 1
    WHERE map.Id BETWEEN @firstBatchId AND @lastBatchId
      AND map.RecordType = @someRecordType
            
    SET @firstBatchId += 4999
    SET @lastBatchId += 4999
END
```

What are the best indices to add? I figure `Processed` isn't worth indexing since it only has 2 values. Is it worth indexing `RecordType` since there are only about 15 distinct values? How many distinct values will a column likely have before we consider indexing it?

Is there any advantage in a composite key if some of the fields are in the `WHERE` and some are in a JOIN's ON condition? For example:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_IdMappings_RecordType_OldId 
    ON IdMappings (RecordType, OldId)
```

... if I wanted both these fields indexed (I'm not saying I do), does this composite key gain any advantage since both columns don't appear together in the same WHERE or same ON?

Insert time into IdMappings isn't really an issue. After we insert all records into the table, we don't need to do so again for months if ever.

Comment: If the table has 14 million records why are you only querying 4999 of them? Or are some of these fixed values actually parameters? What percentage of the table is `Processed = 0`, what percentage is `RecordType = 'Bar'`, what percentage both? How many rows in the other table?

Comment: They will all start as Processed=0. 4999 items per batch to avoid table lock escalations. Each of the 15 RecordTypes are roughly equal in prevailance. RecordType='Bar' was just one example, I'm not always querying for that one RecordType. All RecordTypes will be processed.

Comment: Look at the actual execution plan. I expect the main query to be over the clustered index on `Id`, which is a range query here, one of the main advantages of that index. How wide is the range of ids queries more often?

Comment: To reply to your question:"... if I wanted both these fields indexed (I'm not saying I do), does this composite key gain any advantage since both columns don't appear together in the same WHERE or same ON?"  Please take a look at https://user3141592.medium.com/single-vs-composite-indexes-in-relational-databases-58d0eb045cbe

Comment: And they become `Processed = 1` later? After how long, how many rows? OK how about you give us an *actual* query, complete with parameters, so we can see what's going on. I don't know whether to use a filtered index here for the fixed values if there are any. To avoid lock escalation when you know you are doing big queries: either use better statistics, or disable row-locking (you get 5000 page locks then)

Comment: @Charlieface It's currently being designed, there is no existing code. What do you mean "use better statistics? How do you do that on a brand new table?

Comment: @Mohamad I've read the page. I roughly get how indices are implemented, I'm not sure I have the answer to my question though. I'm thinking the composite key in the sample case won't help, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You might need multi-column or filtered statistics for example. How do you know you have an escalation problem anyway if this is a brand new table? Most likely it will pick page locking anyway. Likewise for the whole batching operation: how do you know this is not in itself going to cause a slowdown? It seems you are doing premature optimization. Anyway, to answer this properly we need to see a query plan (you can share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan), or at the *very* least we need rough statistics on the cardinalities (num of rows) of the `WHERE` and `JOIN` filters.....

Comment: .... We can't answer this without that, we're just guessing then. If you want my guess, for this particular query you don't need any indexes, because the most efficient would be to directly lookup the clustered key for those 4999 rows

Comment: @Charlieface I've read in many place that selecting 5,000 or more records causes a table lock escalation?

Comment: It *can* cause an escalation, if SQL Server decided it was only going to get a few rows and ended up getting much more. If the estimate is high to start with then it would go for page locks from the start. Depending on how wide the rows are that can be much more. Also DML modification statements such as `UPDATE` have to lock pages anyway, so I doubt row locks would ever be chosen (on the clustered index at least). Don't guess, measure it: `begin tran; update ....; select * from sys.dm_tran_locks where request_session_id = @@SPID; rollback;`